# How to set a variable in a chef template?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In the official document, there is only one use case of `variable` for template: the caller has to pass in a hash.

However for me I have a very simple use case. I only want to set a server name in a sensu client configuration template file `client.json.erb`

Here is the template file:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "<%= @server_name %>",
    "address": "<%= node.ipaddress %>",
    "keepalive": {
      "thresholds": {
        "warning": 90,
        "critical": 180
      }
    },
    "subscriptions": [ "default" ]
  }
}
```

It is my chef code:

```
server_name = "server1.example.com"

template "/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json" do
  variables({
    :server_name => server_name
  })
  source "sensu-template/conf.d/client.json.erb"
end
```

The config file turns out to become:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "{}",
    "address": "10.0.1.1",
    "keepalive": {
      "thresholds": {
        "warning": 90,
        "critical": 180
      }
    },
    "subscriptions": [ "default" ]
  }
}
```

How should I pass a variable name properly into the template?

Comment: You're not showing enough there, is `server_name`on the left side a variable or not ? (usually try to avoid naming variables and symbol the same, it turns a pain when there's an error and you can't determine which is erroring.)

Comment: @Tensibai `server_name` is a variable there. I have updated the question

Comment: Rename your variable to sname for example and try again, I suspect there's a self assignation here. (or just that the variable is not a string as you expect it but an empty hash)

Comment: I actually ran your code in local mode and it worked fine. Is server_name assigned again anywhere else in your code? I'm thinking the variable is reassigned elsewhere before the template is rendered. ( Look at compile/run phases of chef-client runs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

```
template "/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json" do
  variables(
    'server_name': server_name
  )
  source "sensu-template/conf.d/client.json.erb"
end
```

Comment: There a few ways to do this that work, though the one you have shown is the "most correct" according to the style cops. Some examples show the `({` as you originally had, and if you need a lazy evaluation rather than the ruby lazy evaluator you use `variables lazy {` to delay the evaluation until execution time rather than compile time.

Comment: how about multiple variable, comma separated possible?  ```variables(
    'server_name': server_name, 'file_path': file_path
  )```